# angular-ui-router: unable to set controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, angular-ui-router

I'm unable to assign the controller for this particular view/template arrangement. I suspect it has something to do with view + templateProvider?

```
.state("foo", {
            controller: "myController",
            views: {
                "main": {
                  templateProvider: function($templateFactory) {
                      return $templateFactory.fromUrl("some/path/to/whatever");
                  }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: I'm not using state that way but shouldn't be a controllerProvider in "main"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know the ui-router that good, but my wild guess is that controller should be set up by view not state so

```
views: { 
  'main': {
     controller:'myController', 
     templateProvider: 'something'
   } 
}
```

Comment: that seems to work. how do I access `resolve` parameters from the controller?

Comment: you mean `$stateParams`? or `resolve: { someValue: 'test' }`
to access `$stateParams` you have to inject it to controller, if you want to access value from resolve I believe it's accessible inside controller with it's name `app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) { console.log(someValue) })`